# SQL Query To Obtain Value that Occurs Only Once

Tags: sql

I am using DBeaver to obtain a list of emails that only appear once in a table.

```
e-mails
john@abc.com
mary@abc.com
john@abc.com
mary@abc.com
sally@abc.com
```

I would like to find a query that returns me only the email of sally@abc.com since this value only shows up once, but I would still need the query to search for all possible values, since I don't know, beforehand, which values might appear only once.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Do you know how to count rows per group in SQL? It's rather basic, actually.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
select e-mails
from t
group by e-mails
having Count(*)=1
```

Comment: Does DBeaver understand that e-mails is a column, and not e minus mails?

Comment: @jarlh I honestly don't know DBeaver, however as the OP seems OK with it I made an assumption; I'm sure the OP can name the column appropriately, it's probably a contrived example.

Comment: @jarlh: DBeaver is just a graphical SQL client that can be used with many DBMS. So the real question regarding `e-mails` is if the DBMS the OP uses can digest that as a column name without quoting (I'd guess no) but they didn't tell us their DBMS...